# Create a 2d array/list in python 3 based on only one number to create a blank matrix

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to create a 2D array/list that can dynamically change based on one number, so say I input the number 3, it would create a 2d array like this, with three rows and three columns. inputting 10 would create an array with 10 columns and 10 rows, etc.

```
array = [
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
]
```

I have researched quite a bit on both google and stack overflow, neither have turned up results that actually help me a whole lot. 

what I have at the moment is a function that takes one parameter (numberOfCells) and uses for loops to attempt to fill the array, it returns `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, so I am open to suggestions to implement this in other ways

**both of the chunks of code below will be creating a new cell using this class**

```py
class Cell:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.infected = False
        self.dead = False
        self.id = id

    def printId(self):
        print(self.id)
```

---

```py
def createTestingEnv(numberOfCells):
    # creates a simulated cell tissue
    row = list(range(numberOfCells + 1))  # +1 because range uses < not <=
    column = numberOfCells
    env = [[]]
    for i in range(numberOfCells):
        for j in range(numberOfCells):
            env.append(list(i))


    # env = list([row] * column)  # create a 2D array/list based on number of cells
    print(env)


createTestingEnv(3)
```

(above) this code returns an error, so i don't know if this is the right approach.
(below) this code sort of works, but it doesn't produce the result that I would like

```py
def createTestingEnv(numberOfCells):
    # creates a simulated cell tissue
    row = list(range(numberOfCells + 1))  # +1 because range uses < not <=
    column = numberOfCells
    env = list([row] * column)  # create a 2D array/list based on number of cells
    for i in range(numberOfCells):
        for j in range(numberOfCells):
            k = Cell(i + j)
            k.printId()


createTestingEnv(10)
```

I'm new to python, is there something I should be doing differently?
or am I taking a totally wrong approach to this? If so, how should i go about doing this?

Thanks, Asher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the arrays need to be filled with 0's, this should work:

```
def createTestingEnv(numberOfCells):
   holder = []
   env = []
   for i in range(numberOfCells):
      holder.append(0)
   for i in range(numberOfCells):
      env.append(holder)

   print(env)
```

Comment: that prints `[0, 0, 0, [], [], []]` when i input 3

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def make_array(n):
   return [ [0]*n for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: sorry I saw this so late... it is nice and compact, but I have already built on the code by @user9510218, and I don't want to adapt it. thanks though!

Comment: @Asher no worries.. on second thought this can be made even more compact by doing `return [[0]*n]*n`